# Select gaps in entries based on timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple table like:
`box`,`some_data`,`unix_timestamp`

Ideally, each box will have a new timestamp once an hour. In generating a daily report for missed entries, how might I select gaps in the entries, where a box has missed an hour or two? Do I need to select all data for the day and slowly parse through it, or is there a quicker way to do this in the MySQL query?

e.g.

`SELECT timestamp WHERE [[another timestamp doesn't appear for 65 minutes]]`

So that my report data is basically...

Missed Entries:

`Box 2`: `2:01 am` . . . `4:01 am` (an entry at 3:01 is missing)

`Box 8`: `6:05 am` . . . `10:05 am` (7:05, 8:05, and 9:05 are missing)

`Box 28`: `3:15 am` . . . (still offline!)

This has the potential to have many boxes, so I want to go about this the most efficient way possible. If anyone has a thought as to how to go about this without selecting the entire day's data and parsing through it, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using only one query I can only think of this option which will NOT give you what you need, since it only works for the case of at most one hour skipped, but does not work for e.g. two entries skipped or so:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.timestamp = DATE_ADD(t1.time, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
)
```

Therefore, I would recommend you to implement this at application level, using your favourite programming language.

This is some pseudo-code about how I would do it:

```
result := [result set coming from your database]
// assuming that result is returned sorted by timestamp (i.e. ORDER BY timestamp)

i = 0
for j in 0..23
    elem := [ith elem from result]
    if hour(elem) <= j
        i++
    else
        add_to_result(j)
```